# Which enemies count for the Right Where I Want You achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The Demon Hunter class achievement *Right Where I Want You* requires you to "Keep a boss snared using Caltrops for 40 consecutive seconds."

Since The Butcher, Belial, Azmodan, and Diablo are all act bosses, they would obviously count, but what about the sub-bosses The Skeleton King, Maghda, Zoltun Kulle, Ghom, Siegebreaker Assault Beast, Cydaea, and/or Rakanoth?

**Which enemies count as a *boss* for this achievement?**

Obviously once one person gets the achievement, they can't get it again except on another account with a different copy of the game. This problem is more an exercise of information gathering using outside sources and *friends* or at the very least one good community wiki answer to which multiple users contribute.

As a subsection of this question, which of the enemies that count towards this achievement would be the easiest to get this achievement against?

Answer (score 3):

A [post on Diablo III forums](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209932288#2) suggest a user got the achievement for killing [Queen Aranaea](http://www.diablowiki.com/Queen_Araneae), the spider boss in Act 1, so the other (sub) boses should get you the achievement as well.

Comment: I guess every mob which adds the boss-symbol on the mini-map counts as a boss. So every special, named side-boss like Kull, Aranaea, Cydaea, etc. But this is just my asumption.

Answer (score 1):

I've just got this myself using Queen Aranaea in Act 1, it's probably best to use bosses with similar mechanics to Aranaea - I tried using Siegebreaker in Act 3 but he moves around too much (with his charge, etc) which resulted in the timer continually resetting even though I was vaulting over to him and dropping a trap immediately after his charge.